# How to adjust Label in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I am making a program that uses this equation:

16*(falling_speed)^2 = height

This basically takes the time you are falling and uses it to determine how high you are falling from.

I know how to use the equation, but my question is this, how to adjust the label to 1 second or 2 seconds?

I tried to make them seperate labels, but that didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
print("""This is an app that basically you time the amount of time someone takes to fall from a cliff, then we will
use an equation to tell you how high the cliff is.
This is a recreation of the app Mark Rober created, by The way""")
window = Tk()
window.title("falling app")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg = "sky blue")
"""We will use time import for this"""
timer = Label(window, text = "0:00", font = ("verdana", 60))
timer.place(relx = 0.4, rely = 0.35, anchor = "nw")
def start():
    mins = 0
    seconds = 0
    while seconds != 60:
        sleep(1.00)
        seconds+=1
        if seconds == 60:
            mins = mins+1
            seconds = 0
```

This line: `timer = Label(window, text = "0:00", font = ("verdana", 60))`
is what makes the text. Is there a way to change text after you have created it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: use `timer["text"] = "some_text"`, or `timer.config(text="some_text")`

Comment: I thought config was only used in Canvas tkinter

Comment: Also, you could have put this as answer

Comment: All widgets have the `configure` method which you can find good reference [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).

Comment: But couldn't you have put this as the answer

Comment: I could upvotee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timer["text"] = "some_text"`, or `timer.config(text="some_text")`.

All widgets have the configure method which you can find good reference [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).